# java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException how to remove this error?

Tags: java, arrays, bufferedreader

how do I get rid of the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`?

Here is the code that triggers the exception:

```
FileReader fr;
try {
 System.out.println(4);
 fr = new FileReader("SOME FILE PATH");
 BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

 String in ;
 while (( in = br.readLine()) != null) {
  String[] lines = br.readLine().split("\n");

  String a1 = lines[0];
  String a2 = lines[1];
  System.out.println(a2 + " dsadhello");
  a11 = a1;

  String[] arr = a11.split(" ");

  br.close();

  System.out.println(arr[0]);

  if (arr[0].equals("echo")) {

   String s = a11;

   s = s.substring(s.indexOf("(") + 1);
   s = s.substring(0, s.indexOf(")"));

   System.out.println(s);

   save++;

   System.out.println(save + " save numb");
  }
 }
 System.out.println(3);
} catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
 System.out.println("ERROR: " + ex);

} catch (IOException ex) {
 Logger.getLogger(game.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

and heres the file I'm pulling from:

```
echo I like sandwiches (hello thee it work)

apples smell good

I like pie

yes i do

vearry much
```

Comment: An ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException means that you're trying to read an index from an Array whose length is too small to find that value.  (For example, see what happens if you invoke `array[10]` on an array with length 5)

Comment: @XxGoliathusxX I'm flagging your comment as not constructive. That doesn't help the OP in anyway. For a beginner, any exception is difficult to find/handle, so you don't need to insult him/her by calling it easy or saying their code is "horrible". Also, true, try catch could be used to handle the exception, but what frenchtoaster wants is to find the cause and eliminate it.

Comment: What @ostrichofevil said. Just wanted to add (as a general tip): remember indexing starts at 0 in java! Just because you declare an array `new int[10]` doesn't mean it indexes to 10. It means it has ten elements being `0-9`. referencing `array[10]` will throw an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Answer (score 0):

Exception is likely to be generated from the below line:

`String a2 = lines[1];`

We are using `br.readLine()` to read from file. This method reads only one line and returns it as a `String`. As it is only one line, it won't have '\n' and hence, splitting it with '\n' will result in an `array` with only one element (i.e. 0).

To make it work, we need to replace the below lines:

```
String[] lines = br.readLine().split("\n");

String a1 = lines[0];
String a2 = lines[1];
System.out.println(a2 + " dsadhello");
```

with

`String a1 = in;`

We don't need `a2` here and we are already reading the line in `while` loop. There is no need to read it again.

Answer (score 0):

In this part

```
String in;
while ((in = br.readLine()) != null) {

    String[] lines = br.readLine().split("\n");

    String a1 = lines[0];
    String a2 = lines[1];
    System.out.println(a2 + " dsadhello");
    a11 = a1;
```

you read a line and ignore it, then read another line and tried splitting it by `"\n"`. Unfortunately, there will be not `\n` in what is returned by `br.readLine()`, therefore `lines` will have only one elment and acceccing `line[1]` become illegal.

Intead of this, you can simply write

```
while ((all = br.readLine()) != null) {
```